# What are the recommended replacements for GaugeService et al. when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

My Spring Boot 1.5 applications heavily depend on the nice annotation `@ExecutionMetric` by [Lukas Hinsch](https://github.com/lukashinsch/spring-boot-execution-metric). Unfortunately, the library is not compatible with Spring Boot 2 caused by the API changes in Spring Boot Actuator.

Using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/GaugeService
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.GaugeService
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 64 more
```

It seems that also CounterService and other classes are missing. What are the recommended replacements for GaugeService et al. when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micrometer is the replacement for Spring Boot 1.x metrics features, check out the [relevant documentation section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html).